# More than 1 @Projection in a @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring-data-rest

Consider that you have an **Entity** class that has 2 (or eventually more) **@Projection**'s:

```java
@Projection(name ="S", types = { Entity.class })
public interface EntitySmall {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

And:

```java
@Projection(name ="L", types = { Entity.class })
public interface EntityLarge {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Date getCreatedAt();
    String getCreatedBy();
    //...and more stuff
}
```

### Question 1

Is it possible to use both **@Projection**'s on a **@RepositoryRestResource** of the same **Entity** class?

What I managed to do so far, is to define one (and only one) **@Projection**, as an 'excerptProjection' in the **@RepositoryRestResource**, and if i don't define any, the Repo uses the default representation of the **Entity**

### Question 2

Is the only solution as many **@RepositoryRestResource**'s as the amount of **@Projection**'s?

Comment: That's extensively explained in the documentation. Did you experience any problems implementing it?

Comment: I couldn't found the answer, maybe you can point me in the right direction, please :)